# Why my query doesn't return any results from RavenDB?

Tags: c#, .net, ravendb

I have RavenDB server running on localhost:8080. I created there a database "CountriesRegions" with documents containing "Country" and "Region", e.g.:

Document id 27:

```
{
  "Country": "Sweden",
  "Region": "EU"
}
```

I have a `CountryRegion` class:

```
public class CountryRegion
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Region { get; set; }

    public CountryRegion(){}
}
```

The following code contains a `test` object with `Country` set to "Sweden", and `Region` set to "EU", as expected:

```
using (var session = _countriesDocumentStore.OpenSession())
{
    var test = session.Load<CountryRegion>("27");
}
```

However, in this code `test` is an empty list:

```
using (var session = _countriesDocumentStore.OpenSession())
{
    var test = session.Query<CountryRegion>()
    .Customize(cr => cr.WaitForNonStaleResults())
    .ToList();
}
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Can you also post the metadata for that document?

Comment: You probably meant to load "countryRegions/27" not just "27". Can you show the code where you have written the document to the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check that the index "Raven/DocumentsByEntityName" is defined for the target database, and that your document has the correct metadata information.

The metadata should have a line like this:

"Raven-Entity-Name": "CountryRegion"

If this does not help, please also post the ravendb version you are using. A fiddler trace might also be helpful.